# ggplot & values: where ggplot get these values if I've set a specific ones?

Tags: r, variables, ggplot2, plot, visualization

I'm trying to plot the wage for each individual of my dataset. In the x-axis I want his/her age and the y-axes the amount of the wage.

This is a sample of my dataset:

`tpens` = is the wage

`eta` = is the age

```
> head(final2, 20)
   nquest nord sex anasc ireg eta staciv studio tpens   PPA pens_real anno_lav retrib
1     173    1   1  1948   18  64      3      5  2500  89.3 27.995521     1971      0
2     375    1   2  1925   16  87      4      2   409  89.3  4.580067     1960      1
3     629    1   1  1939    5  73      4      3  1188 107.2 11.082090     1954      1
4     632    1   1  1950    5  62      1      3  1320 107.2 12.313433     1972      0
5     633    1   2  1934    5  78      4      2   350 107.2  3.264925     1952      1
6    1238    1   1  1937   15  75      4      3  1000  89.3 11.198208     1977      0
7    7886    1   1  1950    9  62      1      5  2000 106.7 18.744142     1973      0
8   11972    2   1  1938   17  74      1      2   750  89.3  8.398656     1962      1
9   20174    1   1  1941    8  71      1      5  2000 107.2 18.656716     1962      1
10  20174    2   2  1942    8  70      1      3   132 107.2  1.231343     1957      1
11  20223    1   2  1938    3  74      1      5   800 109.6  7.299270     1956      1
12  20223    2   1  1939    3  73      1      4   980 109.6  8.941606     1952      1
13  20711    2   1  1944    4  68      1      2  1900 107.2 17.723881     1958      1
14  20837    1   1  1931    8  81      1      4  1600 107.2 14.925373     1949      1
15  20837    2   2  1928    8  84      1      2   430 107.2  4.011194     1944      1
16  21461    1   2  1918    5  94      4      2   600 107.2  5.597015     1929      1
17  22173    1   1  1938   15  74      1      2  1200  89.3 13.437850     1953      1
18  22208    1   2  1935    5  77      4      2   700 107.2  6.529851     1950      1
19  22222    1   1  1927    5  85      4      2  1100 107.2 10.261194     1941      1
20  22276    1   1  1949    8  63      2      5  1170 107.2 10.914179     1968      0
```

The values of the wage ( the variable `tpens` ) are these

```
> summary(subset(final2$tpens, final$retrib == 1))
   Min. 1st Qu.  Median    Mean 3rd Qu.    Max. 
    109     650     970    1028    1276    4700
```

This is the script I'm running

```
final2 %>%
  filter( retrib == 1 ) %>%
  ggplot() + 
  geom_col( aes( x = eta, y = tpens), fill = "red", alpha = 0.5  )+
  theme_classic()+
  scale_x_continuous(breaks = seq(30,120, by=1))
```

It gives me this
[image: PLOT]

How is it possible that the values of `tpens` are 200.000 or 150.000 if the maximum value of my variable is 4700? Where is the mistake? Am I using the wrong kind of plot? Is there a better type of plot to visualize these kind of data?

**UPDATE**

Thanks to @stefan I've realized that columns aren't the best way to plot this kind of data.

I've drawn boxplots for group of age instead, which seem to be better.

```
final %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    (eta <= 50) ~ "<50",
    (eta>50 & eta<=60) ~ "50~70",
    (eta>60 & eta<=70) ~ "60~70",
    (eta>70 & eta<=80) ~ "70~80",
    (eta>80) ~ " >80")) %>%
  ggplot(aes( x = as.factor(group), y = tpens )) + 
  geom_boxplot(fill="slateblue", alpha=0.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

[image: PLOT2]:

To order the boxes

```
final %>%
  mutate(group = case_when(
    (eta <= 50) ~ "<50",
    (eta>50 & eta<=60) ~ "50~70",
    (eta>60 & eta<=70) ~ "60~70",
    (eta>70 & eta<=80) ~ "70~80",
    (eta>80) ~ " >80")) %>%
  ggplot(aes( x = factor(group, levels=c("<50", "50~70", "60~70", "70~80", " >80")), y = tpens ))+
  geom_boxplot(fill="slateblue", alpha=0.2) +
  theme_classic()
```

Comment: Well, you most likely have multiple obs per age or eta. And by default these values get stacked, i.e. your plot is showing the sum of tpens for all obs or individuals of the same age.

Comment: Thank @stefan for the answer. I haven't thought about that and I'm sure now you are right! Is there a better way to plot this kind of data??

Comment: It depends what you want to show, One option would be to use a boxplot to show the summary stats of the wage dsitribution by age or just a linerange to show the mean and the standard deviation

Comment: thank @stefan for the suggestion, it seems that boxplot are perfect for my purposes! Is there a way to order the boxes? The values in the x-axis do not follow the order i gave them

Comment: @stefan i've tried `ggplot(aes( x = as.factor(group, levels=c("<50", "50~70", "60~70", "70~80", " >80")), y = tpens )) ` but doesn't work

Comment: Try with `factor` instead of `as.factor`. The latter has no `levels` argument.

Comment: @stefan with `factor` is perfect! thank you very much